# How to setup coturn for oauth authentication

Tags: oauth, webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

I am using the following command to start the turnserver with OAuth authentication
`sudo turnserver -v -a --oauth -f -r localhost -e "postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/rpturn"`

and I sent the OAuth credentials as following to test the authentication

```
var configuration = {
    'iceServers': [{
        "urls": "turns:turn.example.net",
        "username": "username",
        "credential": {
            "macKey": "...",
            "accessToken": "..."
        },
        "credentialType": "oauth"
    }],
    ...
}
```

the turnserver always looks in turnusers_lt table and returns authorize.  If I use long term credentials it works like a charm.

I presume that the setup is wrong but I can't find example anywhere in the docs how to properly set  up turnserver

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing in Chrome? Neither it nor Firefox supports oauth for TURN, see [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4907).

Comment: Yes, I am using chrome. I will try the other browsers but never thought that the browsers are the problem

Comment: The question is how does someone implement WebRTC with oAuth, maybe sent the accessToken as query param and then using nginx rewrite the data?